# What are the Whills in Disney canon?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, rogue-one, disney

In *Rogue One*, the **Guardians of the Whills** were mentioned. According to [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Whills), they were the protectors of the ancient **Temple of the Kyber**. [The temple](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Temple_of_the_Kyber) was also known as the **Temple of the Whills**, or simply the **Kyber temple**.

Does this mean that in Disney canon "a Whill" is equivalent to "a Kyber (crystal)"? In Legends, Whills were an alien species of Force shamans, but was this changed for the current canon?

Comment: Related: [What, specifically, are the “Whills”?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/122576/31394)

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate. The answer to the linked question specifically addresses Disney canon, albeit mainly to say that there’s no conclusive answer.

Comment: @Randal'Thor The question you mentioned is almost a year old. Also, the *Annotated Screenplays* mentioned in the answer is from 1997. A lot has happened since then, like *Rogue One*. Therefore, I was wondering if there was any more news on the subject.

Comment: Unfortunately, answers being old is not enough reason to ask a duplicate question (and we have a lot of questions that are a lot older than that). If there is a possibility that there now exists updated information, it might be worth leaving a comment for the person who answered the dupe, or placing a bounty on it.